# I get gaps when use Plot3D combined with Piecewise

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I am trying to plot a function that is Piecewise in both dimensions.

I write this

```
f = Piecewise[{{0.35, week < 12}, {0.35 + (week - 12)*0.05, 
12 <= week <= 22}, {0.85, 
22 <= week < 33}, {0.85 + (33 - week)*0.1, 
33 <= week <= 40}, {0.35, week > 39}}]

Plot3D[Piecewise[{{((moisture - 600)/320)*f, moisture < 920}, {0.35, 
week < 12}, {0.35 + (week - 12)*0.05, 12 <= week <= 22}, {0.85, 
22 <= week < 33}, {0.85 + (33 - week)*0.1, 
33 <= week <= 40}, {0.35, week > 39}}], {week, 1, 52}, {moisture, 600, 1200}]
```

and get this

[image]

Comment: Try adding `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: Add `Exclusions -> False`.

Comment: isn't strange that `None` and `False` mean the same thing for this option? And for some reason, the pull down menu which should show up automatically after one types `->` in order to select an option from it, do not show up here?

Comment: Try using `Exclusions -> None`

Comment: Also, to get crisp breaks increase `PlotPoints`